# Android service restarted frequently.. why?

Tags: android, service

I made a simple example in order to test an un-killable service. I'm trying to restart as soon as it is killed by OS.

Everything works well. But, I found that the service was sometimes killed by OS frequently, and re-started again in OS over 6.0. Sometimes, onStartCommand is called in 30 seconds after starting the service. I don't know why.

OS under 6.0 works perfectly well.

My code is simple.

```
public class DataCollectorService extends Service {

public static BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver;
private Intent intent_data_processor;
private PendingIntent sender_data_processor;
private AlarmManager alarmMgr;
private  LocalBroadcastManager a_manager;
private String TAG = "DataCollectorService";

private DatabaseReference mFirebaseDatabaseReference;
private final IMyAidlInterface.Stub mBinder = new IMyAidlInterface.Stub() {

    public void basicTypes(int anInt, long aLong, boolean aBoolean,
                           float aFloat, double aDouble, String aString) {
        // Does nothing
    }
};

public DataCollectorService(Context applicationContext) {
    super();
    Log.i("HERE", "here I am!");
}

public DataCollectorService() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();


}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    release();
}

@Override
protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
    super.finalize();

}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);


    Log.e("TAG", "START");
    Log.e("TAG", "DataCollectorService onStartCommand");


    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {

    return mBinder;
}

@Override
public boolean onUnbind(Intent arg0) {

    return true;
}

@Override
public void onRebind(Intent arg0) {

}
```

And then I also set up the service like following in Manifest.
android:enabled="true"
android:exported="false"

What is the reason that the service is restarted within a few seconds after the starting?

Comment: Maybe it's doze mode : https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html#understand_doze
Why do you need "unkillable" service?

Comment: seems we are about to disrespect the user's will here :p why not a killable background mode?

Comment: `"to test an un-killable service."`, there is no such thing in android world, at least not at "normal" user space

Comment: It will be a real-time data logging app. Yes, there is no such thing in android world, so I put a broadcast receiver, and catches the ondestroy moment. And then I restart the service again. The question is, it is sometimes destroyed and restarted even immediately after starting this app (OS > 6.0). I think that this is not because of OS, but START_STICKY. But, it should be after a few minutes of beginning the app, not immediately after that.

Comment: Do you observe this behavior when the device is definitely not in doze mode (screen on but your app in the background, charging)?

Comment: Yes, I'm currently connecting the cable. Actually, there was exception when the program is started. But, this exception is covered by try/catch. Does it affect the service restarting?

Comment: What kind of exception?